# Python doesn't run Euler's method for widths smaller than 0.2?

Tags: python

I have  curious question about python coding. I have a simple code I used to perform Euler approximations, which numerically approximates a solution for a differential equation. It does this by taking a section of the curve and dividing it into intervals of equal width 'w'.

The code is:

```
import math

x = 0
y = 2
w = 0.5

while x < 1:
    dydx = 1 - 2*x + y
    deltaY = dydx*w
    y = y + deltaY
    x += w
print(x,y)
```

Curiously, I found that the code works for 'w' from 1 to 1/5, but not any smaller.

For example, using w = 1/5, the code correctly outputs (1.0, 5.48832...)

Or using w = 1/4. the code correctly outputs (1.0, 5.4414...)

But if I used w = 1/6, the output is (1.16667,6.27523...)

I have adapted the same code for programs running Euler's modified method and Romberg's method (for approximating the same thing) and they do the same thing for w < 1/5.

I feel like the answer to this is either very obvious or very obscure. If anyone has a solution, I would very much appreciate it.

Thank you

Comment: I'd guess this is a floating point precision issue. I have no idea what you're trying to compute, so I can't explain in detail what's going on, but I suspect you'll find that somewhere you should be getting `x == 1.0` you're instead getting some minuscule amount less due to rounding, and that error results in an extra iteration leading to the wrong output.

Comment: You're expecting a floating-point sum to land exactly on 1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 0.2 cutoff is just a coincidence. What's really going on here is float rounding.

`float` values can't represent most fractions exactly; they just give you the closest 52-bit binary fraction to the number you wanted. Which leads to rounding errors.

- If you add 1/2 to 0 twice, you get exactly 1.
- If you add 1/3 to 0 three times, you get a number a tiny bit larger than 1, but 1 is actually the closest binary fraction to that number.
- If you add 1/4 to 0 four times, you get exactly 1.
- If you add 1/5 to 0 five times, you get a number a tiny bit larger than 1.
- If you add 1/6 to 0 six times, you get a number a tiny bit smaller than 1.
- If you add 1/7 to 0 seven times, you get a number a tiny bit smaller than 1.
- If you add 1/8 to 0 four times, you get exactly 1.

So, 1/3 is fine because it happens to round to 1 anyway; 1/5 is fine, because when `x` is a tiny bit larger than 1, `x < 1` is false, and your loop stops. But 1/6 and 1/7 are not fine, because when `x` is a tiny bit smaller than 1, `x < 1` is still true, so your loop goes one time too many.

---

The simplest fix is to use `isclose`:

```
while not math.isclose(x, 1):
```

… although that will mean an infinite loop if x isn't pretty close to a unary fraction. Of course your method doesn't work for such values, but it might be nice to get an error or an incorrect result instead of waiting until the end of the universe. So you might want to do something a little more clever, like:

```
while x < 0.999999:
```

---

A nicer fix, at the cost of some speed, is to use the `Fraction` type for `w` and `x` instead of `float`. You can still leave `y` as a `float`, so your calculations won't eat up all of your memory and time building fractions with ridiculous denominators when you're just looking for an approximation:

```
import fractions

x = 0
y = 2.0
w = fractions.Fraction(1, 6)

while x < 1:
    dydx = 1 - 2*x + y
    deltaY = dydx*w
    y = y + deltaY
    x += w
print(x,y)
```

Now you'll get:

```
1 5.521626371742112
```

---

But the best option is probably to just keep track of the fact that `w` is `1/6`, like this:

```
import math

x = 0
y = 2
w_inv = 6
w = 1/w_inv

for _ in range(w_inv):
    dydx = 1 - 2*x + y
    deltaY = dydx*w
    y = y + deltaY
    x += w
print(x,y)
```

Now the rounding error isn't a problem; we're definitely going to loop 6 times anyway.

```
0.9999999999999999 5.521626371742112
```